# In Rails, Ajax sorting can't' keep up with User moving items around in my list

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, sorting

In my rails app I've made a list that allows the user to sort records by click/drag/dropping them to reorder.  After each reorder I run the update action and pass along the `old_index` and `new_index` of the item moved and reorder the entire list.  The application works as would expected as long as I don't reorder items at a very fast pace.  My question is how can I improve the design I have to account for a quick paced sorting by the user and reflect those changes accurately?  Also I'm trying to prevent the user from having to click a "Save" button -- however if it is necessary then I can implement that.

**update action**

```
      def update

        if @list_item.present?

          # update the modified item, and then update all items after that are affected
          old_index = params[:old_rank].to_i
          new_index = params[:sequence_rank].to_i

          @list_item.update(sequence_rank: new_index) # update the moved item

          # move element down and shift others up
          if old_index < new_index
            @list.list_items.where('sequence_rank <= (?) AND list_items.id \
              <> (?) AND sequence_rank > (?)', new_index, @list_item.id, 0)
              .each_with_index do |item,index|
              item.update(sequence_rank: item.sequence_rank-1)
            end
          # move element up and shift elements down
          else
            @list.list_items.where('sequence_rank >= (?) AND list_items.id \
             <> (?) AND sequence_rank < (?)', new_index, @list_item.id, old_index+1)
             .each_with_index do |item,index|
              item.update(sequence_rank: item.sequence_rank+1)
            end
          end

        end

        render nothing: true

      end
```

Also I'm using the following gem:
https://github.com/scttdavs/sortable-rails

Answer (score 0):

There are some improvements could be made in your code but they would not resolve the root issue of the backend not keeping up with the UI updates.

As you perform several database requests which together need to leave data in a consistent state, this should be done in a transaction:

```
if @list_item.present?
  # update the modified item, and then update all items after that are affected
  old_index = params[:old_rank].to_i
  new_index = params[:sequence_rank].to_i

  @list_item.transaction do
    @list_item.update(sequence_rank: new_index)

    if old_index < new_index
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

This piece of code

```
.each_with_index do |item, index|
  item.update(sequence_rank: item.sequence_rank - 1)
```

is slower than it could be. This is due to the fact that `each_with_index` has to fetch records from the database and wrap them in an ActiveRecord model class. The `item.update` then invokes a separate SQL statement per each record. One way to improve that would be to issue a single raw SQL update statement, decreasing the `sequence_rank` on all affected records.

```
sql = "UPDATE list_items SET sequence_rank = sequence_rank - 1 WHERE ..."
@list_item.connection.execute(sql)
```

The query incrementing `sequence_rank` could probably be merged with the above.

Addressing the root issue, there are at least two solutions. One is to disable the list UI until the updating ajax request returns. This way you make sure the updates are serial. It has some usability impact though.

Another is to accumulate the updates on the frontend and save them on intervals or on some other events, again, disabling the relevant UI for the duration of the ajax call. This is more complex to implement but potentially has less impact on usability.